# Счетчик в РС

Tags: winapi, c++

Имеется ли в РС счетчик с частотой большей, чем величина `*lpFrequency` функции
void QueryPerformanceFrequency(LARGE_INTEGER `*lpFrequency`)? И как к нему обратиться, если он существует?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Самый "тонкий" счетчик - это TSC (Time Stamp Counter). Читается инструкцией **`rdtsc`** (примеры гуглятся).

Тут надо отметить, что в многопроцессорных системах счетчики TSC разных процессоров могут быть рассинхронизированы (в случае с SMP рассинхронизированы по определению).

В вашем случае лучшим решением наверняка будет именно `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.

Comment: Спасибо. А имеются ли "тонкие" счетчики, доступных функциям С++?

Comment: GetTickCount/GetTickCount64

Comment: +1, не знал про `rdtsc`.